# Download File Link for In App Browser

Tags: javascript, android, hyperlink, download, in-app

A mobile app having an In App browser links to website to download files.

I added the download attribute to force download

```
<a android:linksClickable="true" href="'.$url.'/used/'.$productcode.'" target="_blank" alt="Order" title="Order #'.$orderid.'" download>Download Key</a>
```

It's working on desktops allowing you to download the file however when clicking the link in the mobile app it does nothing.

I also added the javascript in header maybe it resolve the issue but it is still not working

```
   <script type="text/javascript">  
        function externalLinks() {
            var links = document.querySelectorAll("a"),
                i = 0,
                len = links.length;
            for (; i < len; i++) {
                (function(link, j) {
                    if (link.href) {
                        link.target = "_blank";
                        alert("index = " + j);
                        link.addEventListener("click", function() {
                            alert(j);
                        }, false);
                    }
                }(links[i], i));
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In our XML file for the link you can add

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

and the link should be clickable and work.